# Allowed file extensions News System

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-news

I use the extension News System to manage my newsitems and I need to add mp3 file to my records using `[fal_media]`. But in the list of allowed file extensions I don't have MP3.

[image]

And even if I downloaded an audio file (mp3), it disappears when I save the content.

I checked the `[SYS][mediafile_ext]` on the Install tool and I see that the MP3 extension is already there.

[image]

Why I can't see MP3 on the Allowed file extensions?

Comment: What version do you have? With TYPO3 9.5.14 und news 7.31. mp3 files are allowed in my system. Maybe anyone changed the permissions in your system.

Answer (score 1):

As you have checked the system configuration which enables mp3 files, something has restricted the use of mp3 afterwards (as Robert mentioned)

In general `EXT:news` (7.3.1) does not modify the available fileextensions (3rd and 4th paramter of `getFileFieldTCAConfig()` calls in `Configuration/TCA/tx_news_domain_model_news.php` for the `fal_media`field is empty) something else has modified the list.

You may check if `mp3` is removed everywhere, checking the TCA for all tables (there should be some mentions for tt_content)

Then you might check the site extension or page_TSconfig for the origin of the removal.